# why lseek failed with append mode in ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, unix

```
//open file
if((fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND)) == -1)
  printf("open failed\n");

//set offset
if(lseek(fd, -8, SEEK_CUR) == -1)
  printf("cannot seek\n");
```

then it print "cannot seek",this is why?
after strerrno(errno),it shows "Invalid argument"
Now I find the problem,the SEEK_CUR is at the start position.
But Why? I use append mode.

Comment: What message does it fail with?

Comment: What's the current position? `lseek` can't set the position to negative offsets. Use `errno` to check for `EINVAL`.

Comment: the file has many characters.-8 cannot reach the top

Comment: The answer appears to be solved, but for future reference, you can do printf("%m", errno); to give you more information about the problem.

Comment: after strerrno(errno),it shows "Invalid argument"

Comment: Have a look here - http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek if you want more info about it. One of the arguments is of the wrong type. So either SEEK_CUR is invalid or -8 will take it somewhere unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me when I ensure that the current position when seeking is at least 8, so that

```
lseek(fd, -8, SEEK_CUR)
```

doesn't try to set the position before the start of the file.

If `lseek` would set the file position to a negative offset, it sets `errno` to `EINVAL`, which is reported as an `Invalid argument`, just as you observed.

Note that `open` sets the current file position to the beginning of the file (at least my glibc's `open` does), so you'd need to `lseek(fd,-8,SEEK_END)` if you want to set the position eight bytes from the end. But of course that would still fail if the file is smaller than eight bytes.

Comment: Now I find the problem,the SEEK_CUR is at the start position.
But Why? I use append mode.

Comment: `open` doesn't care about that. "The file  offset is set to the beginning of the file (see lseek(2))." says my man page.

Comment: but i open with append mode,it should be in the end

Comment: @LitterWhite No. It still sets the offset to the beginning of the file. When you `write` to a file opened in append mode, "Before  each  write(2),  the file  offset  is  positioned  at the end of the file, as if with lseek(2)."